# Реклама и продвижение проекта

Tags: реклама, продвижение

**Допустим** Вы собрались сделать хороший проект, который будет пользоваться спросом и станет (возможно) популярным (например как Хэшкод).

**Допустим** Вы взяли и сделали его и он получился у Вас "хорошим" (т.е. без багов (почти), приятный интерфейс и высокая производительность).

**Допустим** Вы нашли ресурсы оплатить хороший хостинг (если это сайт) или сделали пару качественных копий дисков с Вашим приложением (например игрой)

Если все эти невероятные условия выполняются, то как продвигать свой проект? С помощью каких средств? (допустим проект ориентирован на IT-специалистов, например как Хэшкод)

Как представить Ваш проект на хорошем уровне? Чтобы посмотрев на презентацию, людям хотелось попробовать Ваш продукт? Заметил, что существует тенденция делать видеоролики, демонстрирующие функционал проекта, например [redactorjs](http://redactorjs.com/) или временная линия [facebook](http://fb.com), видео к которой можно посмотреть на главной странице, если вы не авторизировались на сайте. И тогда ещё вопрос: может ли это быть наилучшим вариантом? Стоит ли вообще делать такие видео?

Вот сколько вопросов, но задача одна: как показать своё творение миру, чтобы он от этой презентации захотел попробовать Ваш продукт?

Comment: Может быть и тема оффтопик, но я не нашёл другого форума в [сети знаний][1]
[1]: http://sezn.ru/

Comment: А че тут заморачиватся, надо бабло, спонсора или мецината и пиар компания обеспечена... А все что будут советовать, типа реклама в гугл, мальчики возле метро, реклама на заборах и по телевизору - это все вытекающие... Ну если сам хочешь попробывать, то читай про seo.... Оптимизация..... Раскрутка... Баннерные сети, обмен линками....

Comment: @megacoder, 

    (допустим проект ориентирован на IT-специалистов, например как Хэшкод)

Сомневаюсь, что этой категории можно что-нибудь продать. Ищите обходные пути (личные контакты) к распилу какого-нибудь бюджета.

Comment: Я не про возможность продать. Я про то, чтобы проект стал популярным.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопросы по маркетингу и раскрутке не относятся к тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Проведу параллель с муз. группой. Вот, мы собрались, хорошие музыканты, сделали программу из N-цати песен, репали в течении неск. месяцев на реп. базе. Вложились и купили хорошие инструменты и кейсы для путешествий с оными. Записали демо, сделали сайт.

Раскруткой никто из нас заниматься не умеет, мы не по этой части, мы - «до/соль/до/соль», люди сцены и искусства, типа.

Взяли специально обученного энергичного человечка со связями, красными волосами и женского пола. И все завертелось: клубы в Москве, фестиваль в Адлере.

**Вывод**: для раскрутки нужен человек, *dedicated*, в этом разбирающийся, и не начинающий. Как в том же фильме "Социальная сеть". Договориться можно по-разному: и за % с прибыли, и за фикс. ставку, и за интерес и веру в это супер-начинание.

Answer (score 3):

У меня в голове вертится только одно слово - "Хабр". Пару хороших статеек, мол, после того, как поюзаете наш проект вы не сможете понять, как жили без него раньше. И стоить это все может 0 руб, а юзеров постоянных получишь.

Comment: Кстати, можно ещё раскрутить подобным способом http://habrahabr.ru/post/147634/. Профит будет больше.

Comment: Такого рода посты на Хабре висят в отдельном хабе "Я пиарюсь", который, поверьте, читает не такая уж и широкая аудитория.

Comment: @VioLet, я же не говорю о посте типа - "вот ссылка на мой проект, он хороший, пользуйтесь". Можно ведь рассказать об архитектуре проекта, об технологиях, которые используются. Если это high-load проект, то вообще круто, можно даже целый доклад написать об алгоритмах распределения нагрузки.

Comment: @Анна_Смирнова, а кто эту статью на Хабре прочитает ? Несколько завсегдатаев ?

Например, у меня просто нет времени отслеживать поток статей (кстати, большинство никчемные) на Хабре. Иногда захожу туда по случайным ссылкам (например отсюда) или из гугла.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, силен ли я в этой теме, но все же попробую ответить =)

**Во-первых**, если вы задумали проект для узкого круга лиц:

```
ориентирован на IT-специалистов
```

То уже можно не рассчитывать на супер популярность, так как "узкий круг" говорит сам за себя. Вы можете рассчитывать на аудиторию 10000 - 20000 человек, пока, думаю, не более. В целом, все зависит от вас, конечно же. Но на популярность FaceBook`а можете не рассчитывать =)

**Во-вторых.** Вот вы создали "супер мега крутой ресурс" и начинаете задумываться о серьёзной раскрутке. Тут перед вами стоит выбор: идти легальным путем или же наоборот - "жульничать"( и тратить на раскрутку в разы меньше! ). Второй способ редко бывает малоэффективнее первого, так как даже если взять, к примеру, раскрутку ресурса с помощью ботнета, рассылки спама и т.д. Первый способ очень "дорого стоит". Реклама ныне не стоит того, чего за неё просят...но в обоих способах вы вряд ли выйдете проигравшими - тут все только от вас, опять же, зависит!

**В-третьих** Раскрутка видеоролика на YouTube тоже требует неких затрат, иначе можете рассчитывать не более, чем на 3-4k просмотров.

**P.S**  А на мой взгляд, чтобы люди ходили на ваш ресурс и с радостью сообщали о его существовании своим знакомым, нужно просто-напросто создать на ресурсе что-то новое, ввести некое новшество в тематику ресурса! Вы можете создать простой форум, но прикрутить к нему, например, мемы( ну просто пример! ) и люди, заинтересованные вашим творением, будут засиживаться там часами =). Конечно же, если вы сейчас сядете и будете писать "социальную сеть для собак", то лучше даже и не начинать...

---

**А вообще вопрос удачный! Удачи!**